# Attempting to reference a deleted function on a struct constructor

Tags: c++

This is my struct, I'm getting the error

error C2280: 'LandCell::LandCell(void)': attempting to reference a deleted     function
note: compiler has generated 'LandCell::LandCell' here

```
struct LandCell
{
    AnimatedBitmap sprite;
    bool isColliding;
};
```

When I click on the note it points me to the closing brace of the struct;

I've read that this can happen if you define your own move/copy constructors but in this case I'm not defining anything, and my default constructor seemed to have gotten deleted.

Edit: this error happens when I create a landcell object, in in my code it's a global, just like this struct so I have

```
struct LandCell {
...
};

LandCell land1;
```

This is the top of the AnimatedBitmap class

```
class AnimatedBitmap
{
public:

AnimatedBitmap(int RMKey);
AnimatedBitmap(BitmapFile*);
~AnimatedBitmap();
```

By the way this error started happening when I deleted the AnimatedBitmap overloaded assinment operator and copy constructor.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Including how you use the structure and what `AnimatedBitmap` is. My guess is that `AnimatedBitmap` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: _"By the way this error started happening when I deleted the AnimatedBitmap overloaded assinment operator and copy constructor."_ False.

Answer (score 1):

> My guess is that AnimatedBitmap doesn't have a default constructor.
>   – Some programmer dude 7 mins ago

That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've left `LandCell` only its compiler-defined default constructor, which cannot be used because it has no way of knowing how to construct an `AnimatedBitmap` (which itself has no default constructor).

You'll have to create a constructor for `LandCell` yourself, and write it to initialise `sprite` in whichever way you choose after thinking about it for a while.